# Dijit Horizontal slide bar issue

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I'm trying to implement a Horizontal Slider using 'dijit/form/HorizontalSlider'. I successfully got the Slider working but the slider comes with a red color[image].

How can i change the color to white or any color that i want?

Below is the code snippet that im using.

```js
 createSlider= function() {
      sliderOpacity = new HorizontalSlider({
          name: "slider",
          value: 60,
          minimum: 0,
          maximum: 100,
          intermediateChanges: true
      }, "sliderOpacity");
      sliderOpacity.startup();
      dojo.connect(dijit.byId('sliderOpacity'), 'onChange', changeOpacity);
    },

<!-- language: lang-html -->

<div class="slider">
    <div id="sliderOpacity">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to override the default theme css with this (using Claro in this example, replace claro with whatever theme you are using)

```
.claro  .dijitSlider .dijitSliderProgressBarH {
    background-color: white;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[The answer by timlohnes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/158917/43079) pointed me in the right direction.

Original theme in the claro file:

```
.dijitSliderProgressBar {background-red; z-index:1;}
```

I had to override it to:

```
.dijitSliderProgressBar {background-white; z-index:1;}
```

Also the dijitSliderProgressBarH didn't have any background color and I'm assuming that it just inherits from the .dijitSliderProgressBar